# H1 tag word with two styles

Tags: seo, html, googlebot, heading, h1

For the purpose of playing with the words I have H1 tag with different styles. Moreover those styles are applied two to one word. For example:

```
<h1>Some<span>thing</span> dif<span>ferent</span></h1>
```

So my question is. Is this ok for SEO and how do the search engine understand it?

```
1. Something different or
2. Some thing dif ferent or
3. Some dif thing ferent or
4. ... anything else
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search engines should understand it as a h1 level heading: Something different.
Use of the `<span>` element in this example would appear to be proper.

> The HTML `<span>` element is a generic inline container for phrasing
>   content, which does not inherently represent anything. **It can be used
>   to group elements for styling purposes (using the class or id
>   attributes)**, or because they share attribute values, such as lang. **It
>   should be used only when no other semantic element is appropriate.**
>   `<span>` is very much like a `<div>` element, but `<div>` is a block-level
>   element whereas a `<span>` is an inline element.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span

Comment: just sometimes the SEO checking sites display this with spaces like in the 2nd example. So I was not sure

Answer (score 0):

Search engines will read this as one line `<h1>Everything in here is a thing</h1>`.

A  tag is an inline container that is usually used from a CSS or JavaScript staying perspective. It has no real meaning so from an SEO perspective you are fine.

John Mu, a Webmaster Trends Analyst at Google, said in response to a question about  and  tags that *"I don't think we use them at all. People tend to be quite creative when it comes to using HTML :-)"*

Comment: How about the question of using tags to split up words?

Comment: The context of John Mu's quote was about HTML semantic tags versus more general tags https://twitter.com/JohnMu/status/1004982329847271424